# Inefficient tokenization leading to better results

Tags: nlp, tokenize, gensim

I am following the code from [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/introduction-to-gensim-calculating-text-similarity-9e8b55de342d).

I have a csv file of 8000 questions and answers and I have made an LSI model with 1000 topics, from a tfidf corpus, using gensim as follows. I only consider questions as part of the text not the answers.

```
texts = [jieba.lcut(text) for text in document]
# tk = WhitespaceTokenizer() 
# texts = [tk.tokenize(text) for text in document]
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(texts)
feature_cnt = len(dictionary.token2id)
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]
tfidf = models.TfidfModel(corpus)
tfidf_corpus = tfidf[corpus]
lsi_model = models.LsiModel(tfidf_corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=1000)
corpus_lsi = lsi_model[tfidf_corpus]
index = similarities.SparseMatrixSimilarity(corpus_lsi, num_features = feature_cnt)
```

Before this I am also preprocessing the data by removing stopwords using nltk and replacing punctuations using regex and lemmatizing, using wordnet and nltk.

I understand that jieba is not a tokenizer suited for english because it tokenizes spaces as well like this:

```
Sample: This is untokenized text
Tokenized: 'This',' ','is',' ','untokenized', ' ', 'text'
```

When I switch from jieba to nltk whitespace tokenizer, strange thing happens, my accuracy suddenly drops that is when I a new sentence using the following code I get worse results

```
keyword = "New sentence the similarity of which is to be found to the main corpus"
kw_vector = dictionary.doc2bow(jieba.lcut(keyword)) # jieba.lcut can be replaced by tk.tokenize()
sim = index[lsi_model[tfidf[kw_vector]]]                         
x = [sim[i] for i in np.argsort(sim)[-2:]]
```

My understanding is that extra and useless words and characters like whitespaces should decrease accuracy but here I observe an opposite effect. What could be the possible reasons?

One possible explanation I came up with is that most of the questions are short only 5 to 6 words like

1. What is the office address?
2. Who to contact for X?
3. Where to find document Y?

Comment: There are many tokenization schemes, including n-chars. Different tokenizers will have different opinions of what constitutes a token. There is no a best tokenizer. Some tokenizers work better for certain tasks, others work better for other tasks.

Comment: As per my limited understanding, I was of the opinion that for text NLP tasks it is best to reduce words/characters that add no value to the document. Based on that, I believe that adding spaces is also adding unnecessary information to the model which does not help at all. Your thoughts @SergeyBushmanov?

Comment: Let's run a thought experiment. Let's try to classify 2 sentences "Well after long consideration I think my answer is no" and "Nope" into 2 categories: "thoughtful" and "not thoughtful". Do you think number of whitespaces can be helpful?

Comment: Also, what downstream 'accuracy' evaluation is showing the difference? (Is it a rigorous repeatable scoring, or just your ad hoc manual eyeballing of whether you like the results better or not?) And, if your conjecture is that the main difference is whether tokens like `' '` are present (single spaces), what happens if you also try removing just those tokens from the 'jieba' output? (If it still outperforms the NLTK tokenization, perhaps it is other differences in the tokenization, or its interaction with your other preprocessing, that are most significant.)